# How to get current path on azure webjob/console app

Tags: c#, azure

I am creating an azure webjob (console app), and I need to get the current path of the executable.

The full piece of code is here:

```
   public static void ActivateFeatures(ClientContext cc)
    {
        XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(@"C:\Users\Esteban\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Template", "");

        //XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\\Template\\", "");
        //XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBROOT_PATH"), "Template"), ""); 
        string templateName = "features.xml";

        // Load the template
        ProvisioningTemplate p2 = provider.GetTemplate(templateName);

        // Apply template to existing site
        try
        {
            cc.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(p2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("App installed finished");
    }
```

A friend of mine told me this line would work on azure, but when I test it locally it doesnt work

```
XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBROOT_PATH"), "Template"), "");
```

When I use the second line I get a value can not be blank exception.

http://screencast.com/t/4tj8YelW

All I need is one line that:
1. I dont have to hardcode
2. It should work locally but also when deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following environment variables:

**WEBJOBS_PATH** - The temporary location of the currently running WebJob (the WebJob binaries are copied here to prevent locking issues when updating the WebJob with new binaries).

**WEBROOT_PATH** - The path to wwwroot.

**WEBJOBS_TYPE** - The type of the currently running WebJob.

**WEBJOBS_NAME** - The name of the currently running WebJob.

So you can use `%WEBROOT_PATH%\App_Data\jobs\%WEBJOBS_TYPE%\%WEBJOBS_NAME%` to get to the WebJob binaries path, note that any changes on this directory will result in restarting the WebJob (as it was changed).

Comment: WEBROOT_PATH is null for me on azure... Also it's not listed on Kudu under Environment variables...  Could you please verify? May be they changed something? But I can see WEBROOT_Path when I run command in powershell console using Kudu... totally confused

Comment: The path is set inside the webjob. I could see that my webjobs_path is "D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\logalerting\citl1szm.tgn". You can navigate to it using "system drive" link in kudu debug console.